# myPhpAdmin, how to create a trigger that when someone updates any column in a row it will add a "1" in a specific column

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a database for a set of doctors in a hospital.
If the doctor updates his/her information in the database I want a value of 1 to be set in the column named "Updated", that way I can sort the table everyweek to see what rows have been updated.

I am using the myPHPadmin

Answer (score 0):

A `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger will work for this task:

```
DELIMITER ;;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_update_doctorb`;;
CREATE TRIGGER `before_update_doctorb`
 BEFORE UPDATE ON `Doctorb`
   FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
        SET new.`updated` = 1;
   END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Alternatively, an `updated_at` field could be used to record *when* the update was made so that not only do you know whether an update was made or not, but you can see how old/stale the data may be.

Comment: I am going to test it right now and let you know! Thanks

Comment: I am using the myPhpAdmin. I have clicked on add a trigger. I placed the above code into it. but it does not work. I realize i need to change the appropriate column and table names but still not working. I am sure it has to do with using the myPhpAdmin trigger editor.